# Summary tables from multiple tables using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv, summary, psobject

All, 
I'm trying to write a script for the following task.
I have multiple physical entities titled like `Entity1`, `Entity2` and so on.
Each entity has CSV table that contains settings for various subsystems of this particular entity. Like so:

```
SubsystemName   Subsystem code   Execution   Trigger   Period   Last ON
SubSys1         ad1              ON          Timed     1d       01/05/2020  
SubSys2         ad2              OFF         Timed     5d       02/01/2020
SubSys3         af5              ON          Manual    2d       04/02/2020
SubSys4         af5b             OFF         Timed     1d       01/01/2020
```

What I need to do is to form a number of reports/tables each summarizing a particular setting for each subsystem of each entity, for instance, to see if execution of each subsystem of each entity is ON I need this kind of table:

```
SubSystem Name  Entity1   Entity2   Entity3   Entity4   Entity5
SubSys1         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF          
SubSys2         ON        OFF       ON        ON        OFF
SubSys3         OFF       ON        ON        OFF       OFF
SubSys4         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF
SubSys5         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF
```

What I have so far:
I cleaned up the CSVs and wrote them in JSON files for each entity like so: `Entity1_Scheduler.json`
I may need to run the audit of the settings for an arbitrary set of entities. Since there is no mentioning of what Entity this particular JSON belongs to in the file itself and the only way of knowing that is the name of the file, I read each JSON in an object, and then I create a PSObject with NoteProperties where `Name = EntityN` - name of the entity and `Value = JSONObj` all the data from JSON like so:

```
$myEntities = @{'Entity1', 'Entity2'} #These are the entities I want to audit this time
$myData = [PSObject]::new() #This is going to be object holding all the data

#Reading only files for entities I need and only pick JSON version of it
Get-Content -path ($Path + "\*") -include ($myEntities|%{$_ + "*"}) -filter *.json -Raw | %{
   $currentEntity = ($_.PSChildName -Split "_")[0] #Getting Entity name from file name

   #This is the data for this entity
   $currentJson = ConvertFrom-Json $_

   #Assembling data from all entities in one object
   $myData| Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $currentEntity -Value $currentJson
   }
```

So, I have a PSObject with a NoteProperty member for each Entity, where Name is Entity Name and Value is JSON data from the first table in the post. 
And this is where I"m getting stuck.
How do I construct a table for a selected property (aka "Summary table" aka "Audit report"), in this example, Execution:

```
SubSystem Name  Entity1   Entity2   Entity3   Entity4   Entity5
SubSys1         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF          
SubSys2         ON        OFF       ON        ON        OFF
SubSys3         OFF       ON        ON        OFF       OFF
SubSys4         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF
SubSys5         ON        OFF       ON        OFF       OFF
```

Can it be easily done with the way I have data organized now? OR should I have done everything different from the beginning?

Note: Not all Entities have all the same Subsystems, so it should be kind of Union (or full outer join if you wish) of all the possible subsystems, and for Entities that don't have a particular subsystem it would just have some placeholder symbol in summary table like "NA" or "---".

Answer (score 1):

If each entity data is stored in its own CSV file, e.g. `Entity1.csv`, `Entity2.csv`, `Entity3.csv`, etc., you can do the following:

```
$CSVData = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\EntityFolder -Filter 'Entity*.csv' | Foreach-Object {
    # Add Entity column to CSV data with name of Entity
    Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Entity -Value $_.BaseName -PassThru
}
# Get all unique entities
$Entities = $CSVData.Entity | Select-Object -Unique
# Using group-object to process each subsystemname at a time
foreach ($group in $CSVData | Group-Object SubsystemName) {
    $Props = [ordered]@{SubsystemName = $group.Name}
    $Entities | Foreach-Object {
        $Entity = $_
        # Get Execution value for the current entity. It could be null, which is OFF
        $Execution = ($group.Group | Where {$_.Entity -eq $Entity}).Execution
        # Remove if statement and replace with just $execution if null (empty) values are fine
        $Props.Add($Entity,$(if ($Execution) { $Execution } else { 'OFF' }))
    }
    [pscustomobject]$Props
}
```

---

You could make this into a function so that you can vary which column/parameter to choose for your summary:

```
function Get-SummaryTable {
    param($CSVPath,$Parameter)

    $CSVData = Get-ChildItem -Path $CSVPath -Filter 'Entity*.csv' | Foreach-Object {
        Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Entity -Value $_.BaseName -PassThru
    }
    $Entities = $CSVData.Entity | Select-Object -Unique
    foreach ($group in $CSVData | Group-Object SubsystemName) {
    $Props = [ordered]@{SubsystemName = $group.Name}
    $Entities | Foreach-Object {
        $Entity = $_
        $Target = ($group.Group | Where {$_.Entity -eq $Entity}).$Parameter
        $Props.Add($Entity,$Target)
    }
    [pscustomobject]$Props
}
}
```

To execute just run the function with the appropriate parameters:

```
Get-SummaryTable 'C:\EntityPath' Trigger

SubsystemName Entity1 Entity2 Entity3
------------- ------- ------- -------
SubSys1       Timed   Timed
SubSys2       Timed
SubSys3       Manual  Timed   Timed
SubSys4       Timed   Manual  Timed
SubSys5               Timed   Manual
SubSys6                       Timed

Get-SummaryTable 'C:\EntityPath' Execution

SubsystemName Entity1 Entity2 Entity3
------------- ------- ------- -------
SubSys1       ON      OFF
SubSys2       OFF
SubSys3       ON      OFF     ON
SubSys4       OFF     OFF     ON
SubSys5               OFF     ON
SubSys6                       ON
```

Comment: Ok, so you're going with array of PSObjects, adding Entity as a column. As I was showing in the post I originally chose to go with PSObject consisiting of Name = Entity and Value = (CSVdata/JSON for each tool) as adding another column filled with Entity name didn't seem elegant enough. Let me step back and try it your way.

Comment: One more question. I did not show it in my example column, but next to Subsystemname column there is subsystemDescription column. Name isn't very descriptive and users might not understand what it's about, but it's unique, and the description is descriptive, but not unique (i.e. many items like "this subsystem is not used"). I need to include it next to subsystemName column in the report. Any way to do that inside your code or I need to create a dictionary outside and use that?

Comment: Ok, the output I'm getting with script as you wrote it is strange: It's two columns, Name and Value, Name having this: SubsystemName, Entity1, Entity2, Entity3,SubsystemName, Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, and so on. Values column having the following: Subsystem1, ON, OFF, Subsystem2, ON, ON and so on.

Comment: The only way to output it normally would be: Collect you$Props (which is just one line) into array $PropsArray and so this: `$PropsArra | Select-Object @{Label = "SubsystemName"; Expression={$_.subsystemname}}, @{Label = "Entity1"; Expression = {$_.Entity1}}` and so on. Problem is I don't know how to form this kind of syntax dynamically, with various Entities each time

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Format-Table to get the desired result.
I did a little example here so you could see the method, and see if that is something that would work for your purposes.

```
#Setting up new generic objects
$object1 = New-Object PSCustomObject
$object2 = New-Object PSCustomObject
$object3 = New-Object PSCustomObject

#Adding noteproperties to each object, so they have different properties
$object1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity1' -Value 'ON'
$object1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity2' -Value 'ON'
$object1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity3' -Value 'OFF'
$object2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity1' -Value 'OFF'
$object2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity2' -Value 'ON'
$object2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity4' -Value 'ON'
$object3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity2' -Value 'ON'
$object3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity3' -Value 'OFF'
$object3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Entity4' -Value 'ON'

#Manual setup of header fields, this could be populated during information gathering
$headers = @('Entity1','Entity2','Entity3','Entity4')

#Format Table will automatically output to console without the need to format anything special
@($object1,$object2,$object3) | ft $headers
```

This will output:

```
Entity1 Entity2 Entity3 Entity4
------- ------- ------- -------
ON      ON      OFF            
OFF     ON              ON     
        ON      OFF     ON
```

Comment: You are basically just manually writing that table. How will this help?

Comment: I believe you'd be able to adapt this to your current situation...
You already have the note properties being added, I was just mirroring it manually to provide an example.
Ostensibly you could do: $myData | ft $myEntities

Comment: Yeah, well, it wouldn't work, because $myData has ALL the information. Again, $myDaya in this case an PSObject with number of members equal number of entities, where name is entity name and value is the whole JSON. The output of what you suggested would be two columns: one is Entity name, the other - dump of the whole JSON. Which is obviously not what I need.

Comment: I see what you're getting at here. In that case, why pull the entire JSON file if all you need is just the Execution status for each subsystem?

Comment: Because user might need and will need multiple reports formed at the same time. Separate table for Execution, Separate for Trigger etc. So I would use the same JSON and the same code, only changing what parameter to do summary on.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote script based on yours (basically just changed variable naming). I'm not getting the same output as you. What I'm getting is Two columns, one is "Name" and I have following values there: SubsystemName, Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, Subsystemname, Entity1, Entity2, Entity3 and so on. And the Value column with values SubSystem1, ON, ON Subsystem2, On, OFF, Subsystem2, On, On and so on...